# Getting correct timestamp from cassandra using datastax python-driver

Tags: python, datetime, cassandra, timestamp, datastax

I am retrieving timestamps from a table using the **datastax python-driver**. What I am trying to do is store the previously retrieved timestamp in a var and use it in the next query to retrieve a timestamp greater than the previous one. The **query** basically looks like this:

```
cqlsh> SELECT insert_time, message FROM cf WHERE message_key='q1' AND insert_time>'2013-10-30 10:32:44+0530' ORDER BY insert_time ASC LIMIT 1;


 insert_time              | message
--------------------------+----------------------------------
 2013-10-30 10:32:45+0530 | 83500612412011e3ab6c1c3e84abd9db
```

As you can see the **timestamp from CQL** is `2013-10-30 10:32:45+0530`. But when i retrieve it via python-driver the results are different( I am executing the python query on a different system and not on any of the cass nodes ):

```
>>> from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
>>> c = Cluster( [10.60.60.2] )
>>> session = c.connect()
>>> q = "SELECT insert_time, message FROM cf WHERE message_key='q1' AND insert_time>'2013-10-30 10:32:44+0530' ORDER BY insert_time ASC LIMIT 1"
>>> rows = session.execute(q)
>>> print rows
[Row(insert_time=datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 30, 5, 2, 45, 4000), message=u'83500612412011e3ab6c1c3e84abd9db')]
>>> timestamp = rows[0][0]
>>> print t
2013-10-30 05:02:45.004000
```

As you can see the **timestamp from python-driver** is `2013-10-30 05:02:45.004000`, which is different from the CQL one. Not only the time is different but the representation has changed. This cannot be used for comparing in subsequent queries.

**QUESTIONS**

1. What am I doing wrong while retrieving timestamps in python ?
2. Is there a way to output epoch time as int instead of the datetime format ?
3. Is this something to do with clock syncs or timezone related ?
4. Can anyone help me with this so that the python retrieved timestamps can be reused to compare against cass timestamps ?

Thanks in advance. Appreciate your help

*SETUP*

- *single host machine running vms;*
- *cass sandbox- 3 headless vms running as single dc cluster;*
- *python code being executed from host machine;*
- *VMs date,time synchronized with host using ntp*
- *[cqlsh 4.0.0 | Cassandra 2.0.0 | CQL spec 3.1.0 | Thrift protocol 19.37.0]*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like cqlsh is displaying the timestamp in your local timezone (which is +0530).  The python driver returns datetimes in UTC.  For what it's worth, the data is stored in Cassandra as a unix timestamp, which doesn't have a concept of timezones.

My suggestion is that you always use UTC for datetimes until just before displaying it to the user.